# Limit of max of a vector/series?

Tags: limits

Do you have any clue on how this can be solved?

$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \max \left \{ \cos (\alpha -2\pi\left ( \frac{i-1}{n} \right ),\ldots,\cos (\alpha -2\pi\left ( \frac{i-1}{n} \right ) )\right \}_{i=1 \to n} =\,?
$$

Thanks

Comment: What is the maximum of cos of anything?

Comment: @user114781, the angles of cosine are same ?

Comment: am I missing something or is every term in that max expression the same?

Comment: I think the notation $i=1\to n$ may be intended to mean that there are n terms with i=1,2,and so on.

Otherwise, they do look the same.

Comment: I think $\max_{k \in \{0,...,n-1\}} \cos(\alpha - 2 \pi {k \over n})$ would suffice.

Comment: @Lost - yes it is 1=1,2,3,...,n

Comment: @Jeremy - No they are not same. just put i=1,2,...,n. So it has n members where n is to infinite.

Comment: @copper.hat - it also needs \lim, am I right?

Comment: \alpha can be anything.

Comment: My post still stands: what is the maximum of the cosine function?

Comment: The maximum of cosine function is 1, but \alpha can be anything for example 20deg. How can we proove this?

Comment: @user114781: Yes, I was just referring to the $\max$ part.

Answer (score 0):

First, it should be clear that we can suppose that $\alpha \in [0,2 \pi)$. Let $P_n = \{ 2 \pi {k \over n} \}_{k=0}^{n-1}$. Note that we must have at least one $k$ such that $|\alpha - 2 \pi {k \over n}| \le {2 \pi \over n}$.

Second, note that $\cos$ is continuous, $\cos 0 = 1$, and $\cos x \le 1 $ for all $x$. Since $\cos$ is continuous, for all $\epsilon>0$, there is some $\delta>0$ such that if $|x| < \delta$, then $|\cos 0 -\cos x| < \epsilon$, or equivalently, $\cos x > 1 -\epsilon$.

Now choose $N$ such that ${2 \pi \over N} < \delta$. Then if $n \ge N$, we have some $k'$ such that $|\alpha - 2 \pi {k' \over n}| \le {2 \pi \over n} \le {2 \pi \over N} < \delta$ and so $\cos (\alpha - 2 \pi {k' \over n}) > 1 -\epsilon$. Then we have $\max_{k\in \{0,...,n-1\}}  \cos (\alpha - 2 \pi {k \over n}) > 1 - \epsilon$. It follows that the limit is 1.

Comment: Could you please explain the first part of your solution where you assume that must have at least one k such that $$ \abs{\alpha-2*pi*k/n}<\frac{1}{n}&&

Comment: Sure. First, I made a slight mistake which I have just fixed. Second, each successive point in $P_n$ is ${2 \pi \over n}$ apart, the first point is $0$ and the last is ${2 \pi (n-1) \over n}$, so every point in $[0,2\pi)$ is no more than ${2 \pi \over n}$ away from a point in $P_n$. Since $\alpha \in [0,2 \pi)$, we have the desired result.

Comment: Do we really need to assume that $\alpha$ is in [0, 2pi)? It actually for this problem can be anything!

Comment: No, you don't, but it simplifies the proof. Since $\cos(\alpha+x) = \cos(\alpha + n 2 \pi +x) $ for any $x, \alpha$ and $n \in \mathbb{Z}$, the limit is the same whether you use $\alpha$ or $\alpha+2 \pi n$. So we can choose $n$ so that $\alpha'=\alpha + 2 \pi n \in [0, 2 \pi)$. Complete the proof with $\alpha'$ and then replace it at the end...

Comment: Can't we just simply say that there is some k such that $(\alpha - 2\pi \frac{k}{n})=2\pi m_{m\in \left \{ 0,1,... \right \}}$

Comment: K would be equal to $(\frac {\alpha}{2\pi}-m)n$. For this particular k, $cos(\alpha-2\pi \frac{k}{n})$ would be equal to 1 that is the maximum. Is this correct way to prove?

Comment: If you want, you can say that for some $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ (not just non-negative) that $|\alpha - 2 \pi {k \over n}| \le 2 \pi {1 \over n}$. But this is where this comment chain started?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and comments. It was a great help.

Comment: You are welcome. (My visual for my previous comment is the real line with a uniform grid of points spaced ${2 \pi \over n}$ apart. Then you can 'see' that any point will be no further than ${\pi \over n}$ away from some grid point.)